# Conditional Prob in R

Tags: r, dataset, conditional-statements, unique, probability

I have a large data set having more 45 categories of drugs. How to find out the conditional probability of a category AB given AC is there for every id.
1, 2,3, etc., are unique ids.

My dataset looks like

```
ID1.AB AD AC FG AB DC GM AC
ID2.AB AC DG GM
ID3.AB DG GM AC
```

Can we do this in R. I tried using prob function in R but its giving me an error.

PS: the categories are not necessarily consecutive. I am considering each category as unique for every id irrespective of the no of times it appears.

Comment: What's the "right answer"? Are these list-objects? All the ID values with AB also have AC values. Furthermore, post the results of `dput(dat)` where dat is the dataframe or matrix under consideration. Periods only at the beginning of a row are not a legitimate R delimiter. And there's no `prob` function in the default packages.

Comment: AB, AD, AC, etc., are drug categories. ID is being referred to patient. For ex., Id1 is a patient who takes AB, AD, AC,FG, AB ,DC, GM, AC. I am trying to find out what is the probability that patient 1 takes AC if he has already taken AC. i Hope it clears.

Comment: I installed package prob in R. library(prob) has this function

Answer (score 0):

I may be confused about what you are looking for, but the simple conditional probability seems to be the following:

```
# Create Dataset
mystring = c("AD", "AC", "BD", "DC")

k = NULL
for(i in 1:45){
  samp = sample(mystring, 3, replace = T)
  k = c(k,paste(samp, collapse = " ") )
}

st = data.frame(1:45, k, stringsAsFactors = F)

library(stringr)

# Number of strings that contain both groups or 
# occurances of the intersection
alpha = str_detect(st[,2],"AC") & str_detect(st[,2],"AD") 

# Occurances of AC
beta = str_detect(st[,2], "AC")

# P(A \ B) / P(B)
(sum(alpha)/45) / 
  (sum(beta)/45)
```

Also, I assumed the categories where stored as strings based on the data sample you provided.